# What do these HUD icons indicate?

Tags: sonic-lost-world

The briefcase icon has been there for as long as I remember. The other one periodically appears.  The icon on the left may be "color power" ([controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaJG6.png)), but I don't know why it appears so briefly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Wiki pages](http://nintendo.wikia.com/wiki/Sonic_Lost_World) for this game (Wii U version):

> In the Wii U version the way you use shields is by taping the **briefcase icon** and then choosing the shield or power up you want to use.

It appears to be some sort of inventory for shields/power ups.

As for the other icon, it appears to be the [hint ring](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Hint_Ring):

> In Sonic Lost World, the Hint Rings have the same design as in Sonic Unleashed. In the Nintendo 3DS version of the game, Hint Rings appear normally, mostly in the tutorial Zone of Windy Hill. When using it, the game freezes and a textbox containing the Hint Ring's contents will appear. The player can continue reading or close it by pressing WiiDSA.
>
> In Wii U version of the game, an illustration of the Hint Ring appears occasionally as a notification icon on top of the screen. Touching the Hint Ring will unveil its information on the Wii U GamePad.

It makes sense for this to be the hint ring since you said it only appears periodically.  It's suppose to be part of the tutorial hints of the game, as noted by [this article](http://www.denofgeek.com/us/games/sonic-lost-world/220605/sonic-lost-world-wii-u-review):

> Every time a new gameplay mechanic pops up in the game, a question mark will appear somewhere on the game screen.